# OneLogin credential not working on API-V2

Tags: onelogin

I have credentials with scope 'Manage users'.
I manage to create access_token but ​credentials work for API v1 (/api/1/users)  but not for v2 (/api/2/users).
The error message I get is:  `{"message":"Unauthorized","name":"UnauthorizedError","statusCode":401}`

I've tried it from python and postman.
Anyone working with users V2 and managed to make it work?

```py
r = requests.post(
    url='https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/token',
    auth=(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
    json={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
)
response = r.json()
auth_token = response['access_token']


r = requests.get(
    url='https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users',
    headers= {'Authorization': f'bearer:{auth_token}'}
)
print(r.status_code)
>> 200

r = requests.get(
    url='https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/2/users',
    headers= {'Authorization': f'bearer:{auth_token}'}
)
print(r.status_code)
>>401
```

Comment: Can you post your request and response for both v1 and v2 APIs?

Comment: @MayurDighe, Added request / response

Comment: did my answer resolve your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue using Postman.

Your Input

**Authorization:bearer:<access_token>**

Correct Input:

**Authorization:bearer <access_token>**

Notice the whitespace between *bearer* and *<access_token>*. I am assuming you downloaded OneLogin provided Postman Collection. With their Collection, it doesn't work.